# Calculate how many days since creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say a record has a created_at timestamp of `Fri, 16 Feb 2018 18:40:53 UTC +00:00` and I want to find out the amount of days that have passed from  the current time. How could I achieve this?

Here is what I've tried:

```
(Fri, 16 Feb 2018 18:40:53 UTC +00:00 - Time.now).to_i
```

But that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost, but Ruby doesn't understand your way of writing a datetime.

```
require 'date'
(DateTime.now - DateTime.new(2018, 2, 16, 18, 40, 53, 0)).to_i
```

Answer (score 1):

**In rails**
If you get the timestamp for the model `User` from the database (not a timestamp string to parse):

```
seconds_from_creation = Date.today.to_time - user.created_at.to_time
```

Or directly convert to days (to_i rounds to integer, check if is suitable for you or customise):

```
((Date.today.to_time - user.created_at.to_time)/(24*60*60)).to_i
```

In a view you could use the following, which returns a string :

```
time_ago_in_words user.created_at
# => 10 days (in my case)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
require 'time'
created_at = 'Fri, 16 Feb 2018 18:40:53 UTC +00:00'
(Time.now - Time.parse(created_at)).to_i / 86400
```

Comment: This doesn't return number of days.